# CSS for a left-aligned text icon not working

Tags: html, css, icons, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to make a simple website editor and I want to make a left-align icon, like for example:

[image: text align controls]

Since I can't find an SVG I like, and I can't use PNG (vectors, please), I thought of making my own in HTML.

I tried:

```css
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control
{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;

  bottom: 0px;

  max-width: 10%;
  max-height: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control span
{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 8);

  padding: 0px;

  display: inline-block;

  color: black;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="format-controls">
  <div id="text-align-controls">
    <div id="left-text-align" class="text-align-control">
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it is definitely not what I want. I would want something like the highlighted:

[image: text align controls]

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: https://feathericons.com/?query=align

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/align-right?style=solid

Comment: Are they SVG? (Can be resized a lot and won't lose quality)

Comment: suggested https://feathericons.com/?query=align are svg icons and, https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/align-right?style=solid  icons are created using css. Need to add font-awesome css library and than you can use the icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a lot of code for a simple icon. It can be done with one element and few line of CSS

```css
.icon {
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:10px solid transparent;
  background:
    linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) var(--p,0) calc(100%/3),
    linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) 0 calc(2*100%/3),
    linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) var(--p,0) 100%;
  background-size:100% 3px, 75% 3px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.right { --p:100%;}
.center { --p:50%;}
.full {background-size:100% 3px;}
.active {color:#1A73E8;background-color:#E8F0FE}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon active"></div>
<div class="icon right"></div>
<div class="icon right active"></div>
<div class="icon center"></div>
<div class="icon center active"></div>
<div class="icon full"></div>
<div class="icon full active"></div>
```

Comment: And how could you round the edges of the selected icons?

Comment: @LuisAFK by adding a border-radius?

Answer (score 3):

As per comments you can use the icons from suggested sites.
But if you still want to use CSS to create the left-align icon, please modify CSS as below.

```css
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control
{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;

  bottom: 0px;

  max-width: 10%;
  max-height: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control span
{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 8);

  padding: 0px;

  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;

  color: black;
  background: black;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control span:last-of-type{
  margin:0;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control span:nth-child(2n){
   width: 80%;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control.selected{
  background: #E8F0FE;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div#format-controls div#text-align-controls div.text-align-control.selected span{
  background: #1A73E8;
}
```

```html
<div id="format-controls">
  <div id="text-align-controls">
    <div id="left-text-align" class="text-align-control">
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>For selected state check below icon's html and extra css</p>
<div id="format-controls">
  <div id="text-align-controls">
    <div id="left-text-align" class="text-align-control selected">
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-1"></span>
      <span class="left-text-align-2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```